# Cannot access Administration > People page

Tags: routes, users

I cannot access the People page.  There is no error message.  If I click on People in the menu bar, the Administration home page is shown.

[image: screenshot]

The other Administration pages are accessible.

[image: screenshot]

Similarly, if I click on Permissions for any module, I get the Administration home page; not the Administration > People page.

The User module is enabled.  I am logged-in as user #1.

I have checked the .htaccess file and do not see anything that would cause a problem.

I have tried disabling the handful of modules I have added.

What should I do next?

Comment: I would check aliases to see if there is an entry for "admin/people" that isn't pointing to where it should be.

Comment: OP says he's logged in to user 1.

Comment: In the URL, if I replace /admin/people with /?q=admin/people, then I CAN access the people page.  I found no errors in the access logs.  I have not created any aliases.  Still searching for where aliases may be lurking.

Comment: @bigtango could you edit your last comment into question's body?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure 100% if my solution will solve your issue or not but give it a try

first set base url in settings.php

```
$base_url = 'http://baseurl.com/Drupal/htdocs';
```

then check if clean urls enabled from

```
/?q=admin/config/search/clean-urls
```

just in case try to clear Drupal cache from

```
/?q=admin/config/development/performance
```

Comment: I have tried a fresh drupal install with no modifications, no additions.  Same result, the admin/people page does not display but the ?q=admin/people page does display.  The People page is the only Administration page that is not working properly.  I have tried editing default.settings.php as well as sites.php.  This may have everything to do with this being a temporary development URL.  I'll keep trying and post the solution once I find it.

Comment: just curious to know if you tried to create content types, views or change any configurations in the config page!!

Comment: no, no changes to the config page.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same error with PHP 7.1. Updated to the latest version of PHP and it worked!

Solution: upgrade your PHP.